# QMdiArea подокно очищается при сворачивании

Tags: python, c++, c, qt, pyqt

Всем привет, проблема такая:

Когда подокно в QMdiArea сворачивается, при разворачивании оно открывается уже пустым

Никак не могу понять, почему. При сворачивании окно как будто бы закрывается, потому что код продолжает идти дальше `adw.exec()`.

Подокно добавляется следующим образом:

```
void ManagerMainWindow::on_addContract_clicked() {
    AddContractWindow adw;
    ui->mdiArea->addSubWindow(&adw);
    ui->addContract->setEnabled(false);
    if(adw.exec() == QDialog::Accepted)
        AddContractToTable(adw.GetContractInfo());
    ui->addContract->setEnabled(true);
}
```

До сворачивания
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Свернули
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Развернули
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте так: `static AddContractWindow* adw = new AddContractWindow();
    ui->mdiArea->addSubWindow(adw);`

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, почему exec() заканчивается при сворачивании окна? Я заметил, что он идёт дальше, как будто окно закрыли...

Comment: Если это окно  - диалог (наследовано от QDialog), то зачем вы его как SubWindow устанавливаете? Сделайте просто `AddContractWindow adw; if (adw.exec() == QDialog::Accepted) ...` и все